# moving rds aurora serverless from Public subnet to private subnet within same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

Hi I had checked the process suggested by aws guidelines [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anxulczlp0k)and [url link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-move-to-private-subnet/#:%7E:text=Remove%20the%20public%20subnets%20and%20add%20private%20subnets%20on%20your%20DB%20instance) related to this issue, but unable to move **RDS aurora serverless mysql database** from public to private, can anyone please help me with this or at least tell me the viability of this process.
I am unable to proceed with the step in the above url : **Remove the public subnets and add private subnets on your DB instance** as it is saying both public subnets are in use, i thought to proceed, but later on I **don't have the option to reboot the rds aurora mysql db**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links that you have shared are for RDS *provisioned instances*, to which RDS Aurora *Serverless* does not belong to.

The answer depends on the version of RDS Aurora Serverless (v1 or v2), which you have not given in your question:

- RDS Aurora Serverless v1: While the cluster always lives inside a VPC, it is only reachable from within the same VPC, see the [RDS Aurora documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html):

  > You can't give an Aurora Serverless v1 DB cluster a public IP address. You can access an Aurora Serverless v1 DB cluster only from within a VPC.

  The cluster can never be public. Therefore, you cannot move it to a private subnet since it already is private.
- For RDS Aurora Serverless v2, however, you can [choose to have a public IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.upgrade.html#aurora-serverless-v2.move-from-serverless-v1), but this is not the default option during creation. If yours doesn't have a public IP, then you don't need to move it into a private subnet.

Comment: Can you provide a source for your second point - "choose to have a public IP" - for v2?

Comment: I have added the requested source in the answer. The table shows a "yes" for v2 in the row "Public IP address allowed?".